# What methods are available in a Sails' generated model/controller?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

When you create a model/controller using `sails generate user`, which models are available? For instance, I know there some like basic CRUD, etc, but how to see all available methods?

PS: Unless I got it all wrong and there are no CRUD methods at all. I'm still learning Sails, so please forgive if its a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there are two groups of actions provided by Sails.js blueprints for a newly generated model/controller pair:

1. REST API: `get /:controller/:id?`, `post /:controller`, `put /:controller/:id`, `delete /:controller/:id`. These are classic REST set that should be the one being used in production. You can enable/disable these blueprints via `rest` property in `config/controllers.js`.
2. CRUD actions aka shortcuts: `/:controller/find/:id?`, `/:controller/create`, `/:controller/update/:id`, `/:controller/destroy/:id`. Inspired, by Rails' RESTful conventions, the shortcuts provide a way to call all the REST actions from browser address string, using `GET` HTTP method only, which can be very handy for developers. These can be enabled/disabled using `shortcuts` property in `config/controllers.js`, and it's a good idea to disable them in production (for example, using [local environment settings](http://sailsjs.org/?documentation/#!documentation/config.local) (`config/local.js`)).